# Wrapping code/classes for another program

Tags: c#, c++, word-wrap

At the moment, I am working in a C++ environment. There are many in house programs, SDKs, and DLLs. What I want to know is, moving forward, would I be able to wrap that code into something C# could use? I'm still learning about wrapping code for other languages, and haven't found a decent source for going from C++ to C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as cross-language interop goes, the C#-C++ interop is actually quite usable. Check out [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx). "Managed" is Microsoft-speak for everything in the .NET runtime, i.e. your C# code; "unmanaged" or "native" means your C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has extensions to C++ called [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) that make it easier to build wrappers for .NET languages.